# How to receive values from Activity to Fragment using Bundle

Tags: android, bundle

> I am Sending values from `Activity` to `Fragment`. At the time of receiving values of the `Log cat` shows `Null Pointer Exception`.

**Code of Send Values**

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("address",sms.get(position).getmAddress());
bundle.putString("body",sms.get(position).getmBody());
InboxFragment inboxfragment = new InboxFragment();
inboxfragment.setArguments(bundle);
inboxfragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

> **Code for Receive Values**

```
 Bundle bundle= getArguments();
   String address =  bundle.getString("address");
    String body = bundle.getString("body");
    addresstv.setText(address);
    msgtv.setText(body);
```

> **Log Cat**

```
02-17 12:31:23.363 19118-19118/com.smsfilter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.smsfilter.InboxFragment.onCreateView(InboxFragment.java:53)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> **Code of OnCreateView() Method**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messagebox,container,false);
    lvMsg=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvMsg);
    checkBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    TextView addresstv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblNumber);
     msgtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblMsg);
    sms= new ArrayList<Message>();
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    populateMessageList();
     Bundle bundle= getArguments();
    //Bundle bundle= getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
   String address =  bundle.getString("add");
    String body = bundle.getString("body");
    //addresstv.setText(address);
    msgtv.setText(body);    
     return view;

}
```

Comment: In which method in fragment are you getting bundle?

Comment: Can you post your log

Comment: maybe you have address or body with null value. so when you try to settext, it crash. check your bundle values.

Comment: @AkshayBhat I am getting bundle in `onCreateView()` method

Comment: Please post complete logcat error trace.

Comment: I send the `log cat`. Please check this.

Comment: @Hemant Please post complete code of onCreateView. Seems something else is null. Also please point to **line# 53**

Comment: I send the `onCreateView()` method

Comment: What are you doing in `populateMessageList();` method?? And also which is the line number 53 in fragment?

Comment: @AkshayBhat The line No. 53 is `String address =  bundle.getString("add");`

Comment: Check my answer. Your keys doesn't match. So it is returning null.

Comment: I was removed this key and I entered same key. Then I was compiled the code. The exception was occurred.

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String address =  getArguments().getString("address");
    String body = getArguments().getString("body");
    addresstv.setText(address);
    msgtv.setText(body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data in bundle from activity to a fragment like in the below

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("address", "sms.get(position).getmAddress()");
// set Fragment Arguments
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

You can fetch it like in the below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String address= getArguments().getString("address");   
textview.setText(address); 
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

This should work fine. ThankYou

Comment: This code is not works properly. `Null Pointer Exception` is occur.

Comment: Where you are getting null pointer exception.? paste the log.

Answer (score 0):

Hey from your Activity

Here you are right.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("address",sms.get(position).getmAddress());
bundle.putString("body",sms.get(position).getmBody());
InboxFragment inboxfragment = new InboxFragment();
inboxfragment. setArguments (bundle);
```

In fragment, you must be calling getArguments in onCreate() where you are getting getArguments() null.

So in Fragment try it in either

```
String address, body;
TextView msgtv;
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_filename, this, null);
     msgtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_view_if);
     Bundle bundle= getArguments();
     address =  bundle.getString("address");
     body = bundle.getString("body");
     msgtv.setText(body);

    return view;
}
```

Or You can use the same logic in

```
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Bundle bundle= getArguments();
     address =  bundle.getString("address");
     body = bundle.getString("body");
     msgtv.setText(body);
}
```

This will surely work for you.

Comment: This code is not works. `Null Pointer Exception` is occur

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass the bundle. You can retrieve the activity intent directly with `getActivity().getIntent().getString()`. If you're not passing an intent to the activity, you can implement a `listener` to communicate between fragment and the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using differents strings key in onCreateView

Change

```
 String address =  bundle.getString("add");
```

for

```
String address =  bundle.getString("address");
```

Comment: Ok But I changed this key values

Comment: The Exception is occur

Comment: Comment the line  msgtv.setText(body);    and see if you stil have null pointer exception

Comment: Yes It gives Null Pointer Exception

Answer (score 0):

When Adding value to bundle you are doing

```
bundle.putString("address",sms.get(position).getmAddress());
```

So the key you use is `"address"`.

So when getting the value you are using

```
String address =  bundle.getString("add");
```

Keys doesn't match.
Change the key `"add"` to `"address"` like below when retreiving

```
String address =  bundle.getString("address");
```

OR

When you are putting value in activity
`sms.get(position).getmAddress()` method is returning null.
So NullPointerException when you set a null value to textview.